# Accumulation point and Adherence points of $X \subset R$: $ X = \left\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},..., \frac{1}{n},...\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

The Set $X \subset R$: $$ X = \left\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},..., \frac{1}{n},...\right\}$$

1. Each value of $X$ set is a point of adherence? **Yes**.
2. Each value of $X$ set is isolated, because is not an accumulation point? **Yes**
3. There is only one accumulation point: $0$?
4. $0$ is also an adherence value?

I thinking Iam making a confusion on the last 2 questions:

The third and fourth question are correct?

I think they are. But I can't formulate a formal answer.

Any help?

Comment: What is the topology? or metric?

Comment: Limit point implies adherence point . 0 is a limit point. Try to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the metric is Euclidean metric.

> for 3rd one

A point $a\in \mathbb R$ is an accumulation point of $X$ if for all $r\gt 0, \{B(a,r)-\{a\}\}\cap X\neq \emptyset$.

Let $a\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

If $a\lt0,$ choose $r=\frac{|a|}{2}$.

If $a\gt1,$ choose $r=\frac{a-1}{2}$.

If $a\in(0,1)\setminus X,a$ lies in between $\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}$for some $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ choose $r=\min \{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}-a),\frac{1}{2}(a-\frac{1}{n+1})\}$.

If $a\in X,$ $a=\frac{1}{n}$for some $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ choose $r=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$.

Then for all cases, $\{B(a,r)-\{a\}\}\cap X =\emptyset$.

> fourth one

Let $r\gt0$. Then by Euclidean property there is $N\in \mathbb Z^+$ s.t $\frac{1}{r}\gt N$.

Then $B(0,\frac{1}{N})\subseteq B(0,r)$.

So $\frac{1}{N+1} \in  (B(0,\frac{1}{N})\cap X)\subseteq (B(0,r)\cap X )$.

Thus $B(0,r)\cap X \neq \emptyset$ and clerly $B(0,r)\cap \mathbb R\setminus X \neq \emptyset$ Therefore $0$ is an adherence point.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $\{ 1/n\}_1^\infty $ converges to $0$ so every neighborhood of $0$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence, so $0$ is  a limit point.

$0$ is the only limit point becasue the points of the sequende are isolted points.

A limit point is an adherent point as well, so $0$ is an adherent point for your set.